# Django REST Framework: Purpose of CreateOnlyDefault

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

According to the Django REST Framework [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#createonlydefault), passing `default=CreateOnlyDefault(<arg>)` to a serializer field

> can be used to *only set a default argument during create operations*. During updates the field is omitted.
>
> It takes a single argument, which is the default value or callable that should be used during create operations.

How is this different from declaring `read_only=True, default=<arg>`, where `<arg>` is that single argument you would pass to `CreateOnlyDefault`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `CreateOnlyDefault` is used, the value will only be used on creation not on updates.

For example:

```
class MySerializer:
    created = serializers.DateTimeField(
        read_only=True,
        default=serializers.CreateOnlyDefault(timezone.now)
    )
    modified = serializers.DateTimeField(
        read_only=True,
        default=timezone.now
    )
```

With that serializer, `modified` field will be updated every on every update whereas `created` field will stay the same from creation.

Comment: Aha! I was thinking that this would be the same thing if the field has `read_only=True`, but in the case of dynamic values (like `timezone.now`), the result is different. Thanks for pointing out this case! -- On the flipside, if the value is constant, I conclude that there is no effectual difference. (There may be a difference in that an `UPDATE` SQL statement may contain or not contain the field in question, depending on whether `CreateOnlyDefault` is used.)

Answer (score 0):

It's mean it can be provided by the API client or not, so when it's checked by the validator if nothing is provided its create a 'Default' value.

Comment: How is this different from just providing `default=<arg>`?